# Is it possible to combine two flags defined in SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, conditional-compilation, xcconfig

In our project we have two compilation conditions defined in our project's xcconfig files which we're using like so:

```
#if FOO_VERY_LONG_NAME && BAR_VERY_LONG_NAME
    ...
#endif
```

For convenience, I'd like to reduce these into a single compilation condition in the xcconfig file like so:

```
#if FOOBAR
    ...
#endif
```

I am very nearly able to combine them using this solution in my xcconfig file:

```
// FOO && BAR
FOOBAR_NO_NO = NO
FOOBAR_NO_YES = NO
FOOBAR_YES_NO = NO
FOOBAR_YES_YES = YES

FOOBAR_FLAGS_YES = FOOBAR
FOOBAR_FLAGS_NO =

FOOBAR_BOOL = $(FOOBAR_$(FOO:default=NO)_$(BAR:default=NO))

SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = $(inherited) $(FOOBAR_FLAGS_$(FOOBAR_BOOL))
```

The issue with the solution above is that `FOO` and `BAR` always resolve to `NO`. This is because `FOO` and `BAR` are appended to `SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS` at some earlier point in the project configurations, but are not explicitly defined with a YES/NO value of their own.

I've solved the issue by explicitly defining `FOO=YES` and/or `BAR=YES` where appropriate, so at this point my question is more academic than anything else.

Does anybody know a way to check for the presence of a condition in `SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS` from within the xcconfig file?